# previousBackStackEntry does not function consistently

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I've been stuck with the following problem for 2 days now:

I have Composable Main, from where I navigate to a dialog:

```
@Composable
fun Main(navController: NavHostController) {

val mainViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
val mainViewState by mainViewModel.state.collectAsState()

val placeResult = navController.currentBackStackEntry
        ?.savedStateHandle
        ?.getLiveData<String>("suggestion")?.observeAsState()

placeResult?.value?.let {

        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {

            setplace()

        }

        }

if (mainViewState.showSearchPlace) {

        mainViewModel.showSearchPlace(false)
        navController.navigate(Destinations.SearchPlace)

    }
}
```

The SearchPlace dialog is defined in NavHost like this:

```
dialog(Destinations.SearchPlace, dialogProperties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false,
dismissOnBackPress = true,
                dismissOnClickOutside = true)) {
                SearchPlaceDialog(
                navController)
            }
```

And this is how I close SearchPlaceDialog to return to Main:

```
navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?
.set("suggestion", viewState.suggestions.suggestions[index].toNavArg())
navController.popBackStack()
```

Everything works fine: when I first go to SearchPlaceDialog, it correctly passes the value back to Main, which calls 'setplace()'. If I do this a second, third, fourth time, 'setplace()' is not called immediately. 'setplace()' is then only called when I navigate back to SearchPlaceDialog. I just can't find what the problem is here.

Comment: What does setPlace() do? Can you provide that piece of code as well?

Comment: In my experience observeAsState() simply does not work with dialog() vs composable() navigation destinations when returning data to previous destination. The best I've been able to do is use observe, but it ends up getting called multiple times. For now we're avoiding dialog() entirely because of this. I would love to know if you found a working solution. Very difficult to find anything specific to this issue.